# Implementation ranking by using a Lucene search

Tags: java, lucene, ranking

I want to do ranking in Lucene search but I couldn't. I implemented Lucene in Java and the code indexing files and searching in indexed files. But I want to evaluate and make ranking function which returns double between 0 to 1. How can I implement this function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: And what's the source of that double? a field? a query part?

Answer (score 0):

Lucene uses [TF-IDF similarity algorithm](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html) which you can [override](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/39125).

Alternatively, you can use boosting - either when indexing or querying. This is much simpler approach and requires less effort.